# Set up new TeXShop same as old TeXShop on different computer

Tags: mac, texshop

### Background:

I just got a new Mac and would like to set up TeXShop so that it behaves *identical* as it did on my older computer.  As I don't want to transfer any old things that I no longer use on the older Mac, I did a fresh install on my new Mac of TeXLive 2018.

As I have custom Engines, Macros and Stationary I copied over the following from the older computer to the new computer:

- ~/Library/TeXShop/Engines
- ~/Library/TeXShop/Macros
- ~/Library/TeXShop/Stationery

The custom Engines, Macros and Stationary work just fine. As I don't recall manually setting up other things, I did not copy over the other folders in ~/Library/TeXShop.  However some things don't quite work the same. The most annoying things I have noticed so far are:

- The shortcuts I use to indent/unindent `Command-[`/`Command-]` are missing
- A file is not autosaved (requires me to either typeset or manually save it).

But, I don't know if this is the complete list in that there might be other things that don't quite work the same.

### Question:

- What files need to be copied over from an older TeXShop (which works the way I like) to get a new install on a new computer to work the same.

### Notes:

- Both are running MacOS 10.13.4 (High Sierra)
- Both are using TeXShop 4.01

Comment: First, copy the complete contents of ~/Library/TeXShop to the new machine; not just the select ones. Next make sure you quit TeXShop and copy ~/Library/Preferences/TeXShop.plist to the new machine and place it first on your Desktop. Log out and back in and then place that file in the new computer's ~/Library/Preferences and run the command `defaults read ~/Library/Preferences/TeXShop.plist` in Terminal.app. Then try opening TeXShop and see how it behaves.

Comment: @HerbSchulz: That seems to have resolved the two issues I mentioned. Want to make that an answer? Sorry for the delay in getting back to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, copy the complete contents of ~/Library/TeXShop to the new machine; not just the select ones. Next make sure you quit TeXShop and copy ~/Library/Preferences/TeXShop.plist to the new machine and place it first on your Desktop. Log out and back in and then place that file in the new computer's ~/Library/Preferences and run the command `defaults read ~/Library/Preferences/TeXShop.plist` in Terminal.app. Then try opening TeXShop and see how it behaves.